# Why didn't HTTP/2 use a different URI prefix instead of complicating HTTP/2 with backward copatibility support or HTTP/1.x?

Tags: http, url, web, uri, http2

Why did HTTP/2 folks decide to re-use the URI prefix of HTTP/1.x (i.e. http://...) and --to distinguish the two protocols-- complicate HTTP/2 so that it handles baclward compability?

Wouldn't it be better if we just use a URI to do its job instead of complicating a protocol to do backward compatiblity fallback things?

Like, would it be nice if http://....etc uses HTTP/1.x, and http2://.... uses HTTP/2?

This way we won't NEED backward compatibility in HTTP/2. Instead, the browser can decide whether it should assume "http://" prefix or "http2://" prefix. Much better/cleaner separation if you ask me. Or even better, websites that care will setup their own redirectors on their old http:// to the new http2://...

Comment: ...and harder to deploy in practice. Also, you don't want to break existing URIs (think bookmarks).

Comment: Could you please explain on what is harder to deploy in practice? and why? About breaking existing URIs, sites that care can put redirectors on their http://... pages to http2://... pages. I don't get the problem with bookmarks. Not breaking URIs is an old problem that even exist with HTTP/1.x, and redirectors seem to e to be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can I attempt to answer your question with another:

> Why wouldn't you want full backwards compatibility if possible, to limit changes required by users, developers... etc?

Ok it might make the implementation of http/2 slightly more complicated for Webservers and browsers but allows ease of adoption which more than offsets this.

Some of the problems I can think of with your suggestion:

1. Users need to decide which protocol to use. Or Webservers need to redirect upon detection of support (how?). Or browsers need to automatically try the http/2 version to see if site supports that (slow). And what if site hasn't fully implemented http/2 yet (see below comment about different content).
2. It opens possibilities of two different versions of the site (similarly some https versions of site are different to http version). This has pluses (can optimise content to protocol) and negatives (maintainability, confusion to users, SEO implications... etc.) but I'd say much more negatives to be honest.
3. Any webpages with fully qualified resources (css, js, images... etc.) would need to be rewritten or suffer an extra redirect causing slowness. Or browser would need to know to automatically upgrade them - which might mean a test to see if resource is available over http/2 first and a fallback to http/1.1 if not. This introduces slowness or possibility of getting wrong resource as per above. This is especially complicated when loading resources from third party sites (e.g. CDNs... etc.). Similar issues with bookmarks and every piece of literature with a URL printed on it (advertisement, business card...etc.).
4. Should cookies cross protocols? We've already got a nightmare with cookies crossing from https to http so this would further complicate that.
5. In theory every single network router and switch on the entire internet would need to be upgraded before a single site could be served over http/2. While that be hyperbole and there would no doubt be workarounds to this, one of the main reasons the web browsers only support http/2 over https is to prevent issues with the pipes and switches in between not understanding http/2. As http/2 is only served over https, and the contents of each package is encrypted, the switches in the middle don't need to know what protocol is being spoken under that encryption and just routes it on as it would a http/1.1 https package.

When we moved from http/1.0 to http/1.1 we didn't change the protocol so why should we with http/2? Granted we did with https but that has caused its own confusion (see below).

Ultimately the current system works. It's been estimated that, on average, servers who upgraded to http/2 will serve at least 50% of their traffic over http/2 already (which seems low to me given browser support). That would never have happened without making it so seamless. Most users don't even realise that a lot of sites they use are http/2 - and that's the way it should be! Hide all the low level technical implementation from average user unless absolutely necessary. In fact there an argument to be made to hide the protocol completely for this reason (most non-techies don't use it and they certainly don't understand it).

On that note there's been talk among some for years to make https the default over http and fallback when https doesn't exist, and that's not gained enough traction for the same reason. It would break too many things.

Comment: For (1): easy, browsers could hint supporting HTTP/2 in User-Agent or some similar field. Just like they already hint support for various encodings, languages, compression formats, etc. Point (2) is not correct: with HTTP/2 you already have two sites, but merged in a single monolithic web server that is bloated. Point (3) the redirects are temporary until everyone moves to HTTP/2, plus the redirects only happen when the browser hints supporting HTTP/2 (so no mandatory slowness). For (4) yes let cookies cross-protocol; HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 **are** different protocols already.

Comment: For (5) this makes no sense. Why would we need to upgrade every router/switch to serve a new application layer protocol (i.e. HTTP/2 in this case)? There is obviously no need for such change at lower levels. --- When we moved from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1, the protocol didn't change, it was only augmented with new goodies. But HTTP/2.0 is a protocol change as it uses completely different structure (much more drastic than the change in HTTPS). --- Using proper URI prefixes (http2://...) and automated redirects (upon browser hint) is transparent to average non-thechie end users too.

Comment: You don't have 2 sites currently: you have the same site delivered over two protocols (well at least one site for port 80 and another for port 443 - same as previously). And redirects ARE slow and http/2 will likely never fully replace http/1.1 just like it never fully replaced http/1.0. But biggest argument here is that you still haven't explained why this would be better? Other than the fact in your mind it's cleaner? In which case in this parallel world where they did this, your opposite would be asking why they didn't leave the protocol alone! I think the current method is more seamless.

Comment: I know that it's the same site but delivered over HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443). Same could be done with HTTP/2 (or H2): different protocol, possibly even different port, but all same site. I also know that redirects are slow, as well as that not everyone will move to HTTP/2 **but** the majority will one day move to HTTP/2 until HTTP/1.x will be irrelevant.

Comment: The problem now is that, by design, **everyone** will have first start a connection in HTTP/1.x, and then upgrade it to HTTP/2. But with the "redirect approach", only those that use old protocols will suffer the redirects, and those that are already on HTTP/2 will not suffer anything (not even upgrades) --- the other problem is that blending HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 into a single protocol where the client has to 1st start HTTP/1.x and then upgrade to HTTP/2, is that the implementation becomes overly complicated, which means more bugs and slower more bloated server software.

Comment: The upgrade part is actually taken care of as part of the https negotiation. Which is why browsers only accept http/2 connections over https. Anyway I think I've answered your question as much as I can guess why they went with this. You're obviously not convinced so best to see if someone else can give a better answer.

Comment: Not true. HTTP/2 still does upgrade first in HTTP when the URI has the prefix http://... -- and the upgrade header is kinda messy as it encodes HTTP2 settings payload frame using base64. https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#discover-http

Comment: Which is why http/2 over http has so little support (no browser supports this). The server still has to understand both http/1.1 and http/2 (as standard ports 80 and 443 are used - I presume you're not advocating alternatives?) so you've basically a little extra song and dance at beginning to upgrade (either using the method they do or your redirect method) and other than that, the current method is not overly complicated nor bloated in comparison. I still do not understand your issue with current method and think you drastically underestimate when http/2 could become the default.

Comment: Yeah HTTP/2 specs contain crazy things which is why most browsers ignored some of its specs (i.e. almost none implement HTTP/2 over HTTP/1.x). I also think that it's cleaner to use a different port, and a different URI prefix. My issue is that HTTP/2 is complicating protocol implementations because it's refusing to apply changes where they belong: i.e. instead of using a different port and URI prefix (changes at lower levels that hardly require any modifications because this is what they are made for), they are requiring modification of upper application layer protocols like TLS and HTTP/1.x

Comment: If HTTP/2 migration takes too long, it's fine, browsers can cache HTTP/1.x to HTTP/2 redirects for previously visited sites, so that they don't do the redirection dance. This requires less change on any code (upper and lower layers of OSI), and at the same time, does not require performing the "upgrade" dance at all (no TLS or HTTP upgraded dance) when revisiting the same site.